# Execute the file open with reffrer url

Tags: php

Hey can anyone please fix this code, Hey When I redirect From domain1.com it will send me to Domain2.com
I want him to domain2.com/?file1=xxx

is when file redirected from domain1.com... The code inside $file1 is not executed Redirect me to //invalid referer!

```
<?php
// 302 Moved Permanently

if (stristr($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'], "https://domain1.com/"))
{
   

$file1 = $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'];

header("Location: Domain2.com/?$file1", true, 302);
}

else
{
    //invalid referer! go back to domain1 to make it valid!
    header("Location: Domain2.com", true, 302);
}

?>
```

Comment: try this code:https://3v4l.org/I0cj9

Comment: i try but not working

Comment: Thank you For your help. But the problem is when file redirected from domain1.com... The code inside $file1  is not executed  Redirect me to  //invalid referer!